# Do I need the merge function for this chart?

Tags: d3.js

I have a sample that I converted from version 3 that works as expected until I add the new merge method to it then the data in the chart is wrong.

here is the original sample in version 3:
http://bl.ocks.org/ramdog/805185358382521b77a1

here is the converted sample without the merge, 
https://jsfiddle.net/jwaldner/r0ew1ju2/

they look fine, but if I un comment the merge the chart is not the same.  Am I using this wrong?

This is the code:

```
     // ENTER
  bars
  .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .style("fill", "green")
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .attr("y", y(0))
    .attr("height", 0)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    //.merge(bars)
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.total); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.total); })
    .style("opacity", 1);
```

Comment: No, you don't need the `merge`. You already have 4 separate selections: The data binding, the update, the enter and the exit selections. Why would you need to merge any of them?

Comment: some examples use it; I just was not clear why and how and when it was needed. that's all. Thanks

Comment: @GerardoFurtado 4? The data binding **is** the update selection, or am I missing something?

Comment: Of course it's the same, but OP seems to be a beginner. It's not easy to them seeing how a method modifies a selection. I should have said "four main components", though.

Comment: Whole exchange Comes across as rude I think